# private instance and getter visibility in java

Tags: java, oop, private, getter

and thanks everyone for fixing formats etc, totally new here

I recently started learning java and one question occurred to me during one exercise, sorry if i missed posting rules:

to calculate distance from one MyPoint to another Mypoint, I decided to use a getter for MyPoint *another* since x and y for *another* should be private and can't be used on dot operation (another.x another.y);

```
public class MyPoint {
    private int x;
    private int y;                   

    public int getX() {             
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {            
        return y;
    } 

    public double distance(MyPoint another) { 
        int xDiff = this.x - another.getX();           //getter
        int yDiff = this.y - another.getY();          // getter

        return Math.sqrt(xDiff * xDiff + yDiff * yDiff);
    }
}

public class TestMyPoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyPoint a = new MyPoint(3,0);
        MyPoint b = new MyPoint(0,4);

        System.out.println(a.distance(b));  // this works fine;
    }
}
```

however, if i go back to the code and change another.getX() to another.x, the code still works. and same for y.

```
public class MyPoint {
    private int x;
    private int y;              

    public MyPoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }     

    public int getX() {             
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {            
        return y;
    } 

    public double distance(MyPoint another) { 
        int xDiff = this.x - another.x;                         //no getter
        int yDiff = this.y - another.y;                         //no getter

        return Math.sqrt(xDiff * xDiff + yDiff * yDiff);
    }
}


public class TestMyPoint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyPoint a = new MyPoint(3,0);
        MyPoint b = new MyPoint(0,4);

        System.out.println(a.distance(b));  // this still works fine;
    }
}
```

i thought since *another* is a MyPoint class and instance x and y are private, there's no way for .x and .y to work, and that's the whole point of setting instance private and uses a getter.

what did i miss?

Answer (score 7):

`private` means that the fields can only be accessed from within `MyPoint`. It doesn't mean that they can only be accessed from with *the same instance* of `MyPoint`. It's perfectly legitimate for methods that operate on "other" instances, especially `equals` and `compareTo`, to access private state in other instances of the same class.

Comment: so private only prevent a totally different class from accessing an instance, but allow same class objects and methods to access, even when objects are different, as long as they are belong to the same class. am i getting it right? thanks!

Comment: Right. Access control applies to classes, not objects (instances).